# What is the full form of BRP in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, model

In [this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-93818-9_51) paper, the author has mentioned about a model named BRP related to Machine Learning whose full form has not been provided. I googled the term BRP but couldn't land to a reliable answer. Is it Bayesian Regularization Pruning? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure they refer to Bayesian Personalized Ranking:

[Bayesian Personalized Ranking from Implicit Feedback](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.2618.pdf)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it seems like Box office Revenue Prediction model mentioned at the 6th reference

> Zheng, J., Zhou, S.: Modeling on box-office revenue prediction of movie based on neural network. J. Comput. Appl. 34(3), 742–748 (2014)

Though if you look at the abstract of this paper, they are also using BPNN for modelling. Which implicates that author here does not mean BRP as a ML algorithm but rather using the features and data preprocessing techniques as mentioned in the paper above, before feeding it to BPNN. And the second result of BPNN is from the features that the Author has mentioned in the paper himself.

A better way to solve this query is to contact the Author and ask him directly.